# Правильная загрузка больших файлов, PHP

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет. Задался вопросом, как правильно отдавать пользователю на загрузку большой файл? Использую Laravel, при стандартном подходе `response()->download()` весь файл грузится в память. Как быть с большими файлами? Какой принцип их загрузки? Рад любому пояснению.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/151795/ посмотри здесь, очень годный материал :) как раз по твоей теме

Comment: Отличный пост, перечитаю :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Вариант 1 - сделайте отдачу файлов в обход laravel (простой cdn-сайт
>   создайте, который будет отдавать ваши файлы)
>
> Сделайте вместе `Response::download()` свой метод:
>
> ```
> function sendFile($path, $name = null, array $headers = array())
> {
>     if (is_null($name)) $name = basename($path);
>     $headers = array_merge(array(
>         'Content-Description'       => 'File Transfer',
>         'Content-Type'              => File::mime(File::extension($path)),
>         'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
>         'Expires'                   => 0,
>         'Cache-Control'             => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
>         'Pragma'                    => 'public',
>         'Content-Length'            => File::size($path),
>     ), $headers);
>
>     $response = new Response('', 200, $headers);
>     $response->header('Content-Disposition', $response->disposition($name));
>
>     if (Config::get('session.driver') !== '')
>     {
>         Session::save();
>     }
>
>     ob_end_clean();
>     $response->send_headers();
>
>     if ($fp = fread($path, 'rb')) {
>         while(!feof($fp) and (connection_status()==0)) {
>             print(fread($fp, 8192));
>             flush();
>         }
>     }
>
>     Event::fire('laravel.done', array($response));
>     $response->foundation->finish();
>
>     exit;
> }
> ```

Взято из [первой ссылки по результату поиска в Гугл](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15942497/why-dont-large-files-download-easily-in-laravel)

[Или вот это почитайте](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/download-from-laravel-storage-without-loading-whole-file-in-memory)

А если не хватит - [поищите тут](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&ei=d5H1XNjGN-iXmwWXvqK4Dg&q=laravel%20big%20size%20file%20download&oq=laravel%20big%20size%20file%20do&gs_l=psy-ab.1.0.33i22i29i30.20359.21805..22821...0.0..0.273.677.1j2j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j33i21j33i160j35i39j0i22i30.GYMvfZLNreg)

Comment: Спасибо большое, я немножко не в ту сторону копал)